# create an xml of views and attributes from storyboard / xib

Tags: ios, storyboard

Is there a way to create a xml document with all the elements and attributes from storyboard / xib

I am trying to figure out a way / code snippet that can be used via method-swizzling to generate a blue print of all the views and their attributes of an iOS application.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to this:

Right click on the `.storyboard` file and:

[image]

Comment: I want to do it programatically.I am looking for a solution wherein, My snippet would traverse through the app and create a view hierarchy.

Comment: Please, edit your question with your wants.. And add the word programatically